# Does Powershell Invoke-SqlCmd support ConnectionString in SQLPS

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd, sqlps

I have a PS script I wrote to insert/update a SQL DB.
I create my connection string and then build some other parameters and then use Invoke-SqlCmd

```
$sqlConnString = "Server=$SQLServer; Database=$SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $sqlPwd; TrustServerCertificate=True;"

$sqlCmdParameters = @{
    InputFile = $callSqlScriptFile
    QueryTimeout = 1800
    ConnectionString = $sqlConnString
    Variable = $sqlCmdVariables
}
try {
    Invoke-SqlCmd @sqlCmdParameters
} catch {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Encountered Error:"$_.Exception.Message
}
```

I have 3 servers that I’m testing this on. It works on server 1 and 2, but not on server 3.
The error I get on Server 3 is: *A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'*.

All three servers are PowerShell v5.1.x
Server 1 is Windows Server 2022, and servers 2 and 3 are Windows Server 2016.

When I run the following PS Command, I get this for each server:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "*Sql*"

- Server 1: ModuleType > Manifest, Version > 15.0, Name > SQLPS
- Server 2: ModuleType > Script, Version > 22.2.0, Name > SqlServer
- Server 3: ModuleType > Script, Version > 22.2.0, Name > SqlServer 
    – and-- ModuleType > Manifest, Version > 1.0, Name > SQLPS
```

The only thing I can gather is that on server 1, SQLPS is at version 15.0 and I’m assuming `ConnectionString` is supported.

- Server 2 is using SqlServer and I know `ConnectionString` is supported.
- Server 3 is using both and I’m wondering if there is a conflict and it defaults SQLPS version 1.0 and `ConnectionString` is not supported.

However, if I run the following on server 3, it says *`Source = SqlServer`*

```
get-command Invoke-Sqlcmd
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to remove SQLPS from server 3, or update to version 15.0, or if this is even the issue.

Comment: Try to debug the parameters used, like adding `Write-Host @sqlCmdParameters` to see if they really match your expectations.

Comment: What is the reason to keep SQLPS? It is deprecated and will be removed. There is a large difference between the versions of SQLPS on Server 1 and Server 3.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to remove SQLPS 1.0, or even update it. I tried Remove/Update/Uninstall-Module for it, but says no match was found.